# mongodb not detecting unique value in my node js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on mongodb with node js and I realized that even though I used the unique true property on unique fields in my project, I realized that it doesn't work, what is the reason?

my code is like this

```js
const CourseSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
     required : true,
     unique:true
   
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

i want to prevent this code from saving duplicate usernames.

Comment: In multiple **databases**? Or do you just mean you want the name to be unique in the DB you’re using?

Comment: in the database I use

Comment: Can you add example documents that where saved with the same `name`. Also, try to open MongoDB in Compass, and navigate to the `courses` collection. After that go to the `Indexes` tab, and check if the `unique` index is present there.

Comment: thank you, now I found the option you mentioned in the settings, I discovered something new thanks to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many ways, but I realized that this problem is version-related.

I found the solution by updating the version, thank you for your solution support.

Answer (score 0):

Such a check if not directly possible with the mongoDB library. However it is supported out of the box if you use [mongoosejs](https://mongoosejs.com/)

Comment: I am using mongoose and ejs

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that you already have duplicate values in your document before defining this property Delete the messed data from the MongoDB collections,
or make sure that mongodb auto indexing is true

```
  mongoose.connect('url', {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true, 
        autoIndex: true, 
    })
```